# Enable spectacle keybindings with sublime text 2 on OSX Mavericks

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks, key-bindings

I'm using [spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) on Mavericks (OSX 10.9). The default keybinding is <kbd>super + alt + left</kbd> pushes your current window to the left side of the screen and <kbd>super + alt + right</kbd> pushes your current window to the right side of the screen. This works great with most of my applications, except from sublime text 2. I tried to change the default sublime text keybindings by removing the following lines:

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+left"], "command": "prev_view" },
{ "keys": ["super+alt+right"], "command": "next_view" },
```

but I'm still unable to use spectacle appropriately to move my sublime editor around my screen.

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. According to the official website, the default key binding could be modified by overwrite default ones in your own (User) config file via "Preference -> Key Biding" menu, and I tried nullify the view switching behavior with

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+alt+left"],"command":"noop"},
    { "keys": ["super+alt+right"],"command": "noop"}
]
```

This doesn't work because it basically ignored the key-combo press, rather than passing over the registered key press to other Applications (Spectacle in this case).

One potential solution is to change the Spectacle key binding, but I don't want to.